# Register many property editors

Tags: grails

I have a problem in registering custom property editor. I register it like this:

```
class BooleanEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

   public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
      registry.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class,
         new CustomBooleanEditor(CustomBooleanEditor.VALUE_YES, CustomBooleanEditor.VALUE_NO, false))
      registry.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class,
         new CustomBooleanEditor(CustomBooleanEditor.VALUE_ON, CustomBooleanEditor.VALUE_OFF, true))
   }
}
```

But the only first is applied. Is it possible to register more then one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set one property editor per class.  If you are using Spring's [`CustomBooleanEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomBooleanEditor.html), you can either use the default values ("true"/"on"/"yes"/"1", "false"/"off"/"no"/"0") with the one-arg constructor, or exactly one string each for true and false.  If you need something more flexible, you'll have to implement your own property editor.  For example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor

class MyBooleanEditor extends CustomBooleanEditor {

    def strings = [
        (VALUE_YES): true, 
        (VALUE_ON): true,
        (VALUE_NO): false,
        (VALUE_OFF): false
    ]

    MyBooleanEditor() {
        super(false)
    }

    void setAsText(String text) {
        def val = strings[text.toLowerCase()]
        if (val != null) {
            setValue(val)
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid boolean value [" + text + "]")
        }
    }
}
```